# How to upload image with base64 format?

Tags: c#

I am trying to do image upload with base64 format using httpclient, anybody has experienced on this?

```
            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

                var detect = new Dictionary<string, string>
                {
                   { "api_key", API_KEY },
                   { "api_secret", API_SECRET },
                   { "urls", _base64 }
                };

                var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(detect);
                var response = await client.PostAsync(DETECT_URL, content);

                HttpStatusCode _statusCode = response.StatusCode;

            }
```

the above codes returns BadRequest, please help

many thanks in advance

Don

Comment: Is there some sort of message in the response? Try `var responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()` Hopefully it should tell you why it is a bad request.

Answer (score 1):

a,
`FormUrlEncodedContent` is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` not `application/json`.

b, 
If you have the image loaded you can convert it to base64 using this:

```
    public string ImageToBase64(Image image)
    {
        using (MemoryStream m = new MemoryStream())
        {
            image.Save(m, image.RawFormat);
            byte[] imageBytes = m.ToArray();

            // Convert byte[] to Base64 String
            string base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(imageBytes);
            return base64String;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hi, but I also neet to pass the api_key and api_secret parameter.. how to pass them also?

Comment: Check the documentation of the API. Its difficult to help without knowing what API are you trying to send the request to.

Comment: Thanks, I am in trial period of Skybiometry API, I need to upload an image for face regonition processing, to upload an image, their API requires 3 parameters:

- api_key
- api_secret
- image_url or image_file (file read from local folder)

Since I don't want to keep image in my web folder, is it possible to upload it in base64 format? .. 

I asked to their tech support, they suggest me to use multipart content, but I am not sure and I don't know how..

please help

thanks